# parse server: “curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, express, parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I successfully deployed parse server to AWS beanstalk but it does not response to request.

In the beanstalk environment, I set “NODE_ENV=production”, “PARSE_MOUNT=/parse”
and “SERVER_URL=http://ec2-161-189-119-69.cn-northwest-1.compute.amazonaws.com.cn”.
APP_ID, DATABASE_URI, and MASTER_KEY are also set.

However, when I type "curl -X POST -H ‘X-Parse-Application-Id: UcQ8spwcu8gkatSvxp5dLfjQJvg32uUJIQLDgVjf’ -H ‘Content-Type: application/json’ -d ‘{“foo”:“bar3”}’ ec2-161-189-119-69.cn-northwest-1.compute.amazonaws.com.cn/parse/classes/TestObject", the response is “curl: (52) Empty reply from server”.

If I type “curl -X GET   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: UcQ8spwcu8gkatSvxp5dLfjQJvg32uUJIQLDgVjf"   ec2-161-189-119-69.cn-northwest-1.compute.amazonaws.com.cn/parse/classes/TestObject”, it returns a html page.

Moreover, I tested the project locally and everything works fine.

This happens after I uploaded the code to beanstalk.

Does anyone know why this happens? Also, do I need to set a port number?

Thanks

Comment: hello, is your service a multi-container docker?

Comment: @AugustoAccorsi no, it is a purely express.js application

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this error is happening because you might be mapping your EB load balancer ports incorrectly, the 52 via curl means that you are receiving an HTTP 502 error.

I had a similar issue with multi-container docker at Beanstalk and fixing the load balance reports solved my problem.

Make sure that you have the process and the listeners configured correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sudo nano  /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

and replace this setting with false

## Enable security features

xpack.security.enabled: **false**

*and restart, it's works for me*
**Thanks.**